# BPMN Cycle Time Analysis

Tags: bpmn

I have accounted the walk around the BPMN diagram with this formula:

```
CT = ∑t(task(i))
```

my calculus

```
 5+40+0.6*(120+20+10)+0.4*(150+60+0.8*(30+20+10)+(48))

Task 5 = 60/(1-0.2) = 48
```

[image: cycle time]

1. is this correct calculation?
2. if we put parallel gate behind Task 2, do we need to compute only the path that have higher probability?

[image]

Comment: 1. calculation is correct.
2. we have to compute all paths

Comment: I think that the formula for repetition of path in gateway executed once is (1+r)t and if the path is executed multiple times is t/(1-r)